# Empty array when calling function(java)

Tags: java, class, object, methods, arraylist

so I have this code that input stuff and store it to an listarray

```
public class manage extends admin{
public ArrayList<Game> thegame = new ArrayList<Game>();
public List<Game> ajout_jeux() { 
    boolean loop = true;

    while(loop) {
        Scanner agame = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("name: \n");
        String Cgame = agame.nextLine();
        Scanner qty = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("the qty: \n");
        int CQty = qty.nextInt();


        Console wertgame = new Console(Cgame,Cqty);
        thegame.add(new Game(Cgame,Cqty));

        System.out.println("continue?");
        Scanner autre = new Scanner(System.in);
        int continu = other.nextInt();
        if(continu==1) {

        }
        else if(continu==2) {
            Main.menu();
        }
    }

    return thegame; 
}
```

and a method in this class that should print the array:

```
public void information(List<Game> thegame) {  
        System.out.print(thegame);

    }}
```

And then,from another class I need to call it like this

```
 manage management = new manage(); //the instance
 manage.information();
```

Theres no erros,however,even if I take care of creating an object and putting it in array before trying to print the array, when I call manage.information(); it just return an empty [] list.I dont know why?

heres the class that needs to calls it

```
public class themenu{
    public static void adminmenu(){

    boolean loop=true;
    while(loop){


        System.out.print("1:List items \n");
        System.out.print("4:Add \n");
        System.out.print("6:Infos \n");
        System.out.print("7:Quit \n");
        System.out.print("Choice:");
        Scanner choiceuser = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userchoix = choiceuser.nextLine();
        manage management = new manage();
        if(userchoice.equals("1")){
            manage.information(thegame);   //here I get the error
        }


        else if(userchoice.equals("4")){

                manage.ajout_jeux();

                }
```

thank you

Comment: You're calling `information` without a parameter?

Comment: My bad, I pasted the wrong code,edit made.And yes I need to be able to call information without parameters,since my arraylist is not created/or initialzed when im calling it from my other class.It just get created in manage class

Comment: Why do you create new `Scanner` instances for each request of user input? You only need one instace for the whole class.

Comment: I know that, but my question isnt actually about this.thank you tho

Comment: That's not an array, that's a list, and you can't call `information` with no parameters if it is declared to take one parameter.

Comment: What does `Game(Cgame,Cqty)` do? Does it modify the list?

Comment: @jhamon it creates a new Game object with required parameters(Cgame,Cqty)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `manage.ajout_jeux` before `manage.information();` and then  pass that list to information method. But please note that currently the return type of `ajout_jeux` method is`List<Jeux>` while you are returning from inside the method `List<Game>`. So you need to fix that also. Method invocation will look like this

```
 manage management = new manage(); //the instance
 manage.information(yourListName);
```

Comment: "But please note that currently the return type of ajout_jeux method isList<Jeux> while you are returning from inside the method List<Game>. So you need to fix that also. " I dont understand what you mean.Im quite beginning in java

Comment: Change public List<Jeux> ajout_jeux() to public List<Game> ajout_jeux() in your code

Comment: @Phil_oneil You can use some java IDE for coding

Comment: Well it doesnt work as I wouldd want to.Actually, I have an option that directly access ajout_jeux(),wich create an object and add it to the list.information(List<Game>thegame) needs to print out that list.However, what you told me to do actually ask again for inputs and add them to list before printing it.But I want to be able to display the list without having to input a new object.Thank you

Comment: I get error thegame cannot be resolved to a variable.Keep in mind im calling it from another class

Comment: @Phil_oneil You need to pass the name of the list about which you mentioned in comment "wich create an object and add it to the list..."

Comment: the name list is "thegame". when from my other class I call manage.information(thegame);, I get error "thegame cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Please paste your another class

Comment: @Phil_oneil no where you have defined variable thegame. Define it for e.g. List<Game> thegame = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: well thegame is actually my list im trying to print.. so I create a variable List<Game> thegame = new ArrayList<>(); in adminmenu()?

Comment: @Phil_oneil read some java tutorial or book. You are lacking the basis

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling the type of the object

```
 manage management = new manage(); //the instance
 manage.information();
```

you should call the method inside the object and pass an array to it.

```
management.information(new ArrayList<Game>());
```

Comment: another thing, if you wanna print the arrays elemets, you should iterate over this list, and print each element.